# Replace values in Tidy Table

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, dplyr

I have ta table with count data: I am trying to remove all non-zero values with one. 
[image]

This is what I have tried:

```
div.summary<- raw.data %>% select (Site, 5:55) %>% 
  group_by(Site) %>% summarise_all(sum) %>%  mutate_if(replace(2:52, >0, 1))
```

Comment: ```div.summary<- raw.data %>% select (Site, 5:55) %>% 
  group_by(Site) %>% summarise_all(sum) %>% div.summary[div.summary >0] <- 1```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
div.summary<- raw.data %>% 
  select (Site, 5:55) %>% 
  group_by(Site) %>% 
  summarise_all(sum) %>%  
  mutate_at(vars(2:52),
            funs(if_else(. == 0, 1, .)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

raw.data %>% 
  select (Site, 5:55) %>%
  mutate(across(!Site, ~+as.logical(.x)))
```

demonstration on toy_data

```r
set.seed(1)
raw.data <- data.frame(Site = LETTERS[1:26],
                       col1 = sample(0:3, 26, T),
                       col2 = sample(0:2, 26, T),
                       col3 = sample(0:3, 26, T))
raw.data
#>    Site col1 col2 col3
#> 1     A    0    1    1
#> 2     B    3    0    1
#> 3     C    2    0    3
#> 4     D    0    1    3
#> 5     E    1    1    1
#> 6     F    0    1    1
#> 7     G    2    0    0
#> 8     H    2    2    1
#> 9     I    1    0    1
#> 10    J    1    2    1
#> 11    K    2    1    1
#> 12    L    2    1    0
#> 13    M    0    1    2
#> 14    N    0    1    2
#> 15    O    0    2    3
#> 16    P    1    1    1
#> 17    Q    1    0    2
#> 18    R    1    2    2
#> 19    S    1    1    3
#> 20    T    2    0    1
#> 21    U    0    0    3
#> 22    V    2    2    2
#> 23    W    0    1    2
#> 24    X    0    1    0
#> 25    Y    0    2    3
#> 26    Z    0    2    0
library(dplyr)

raw.data %>%
  mutate(across(!Site, ~+as.logical(.x)))

#>    Site col1 col2 col3
#> 1     A    0    1    1
#> 2     B    1    0    1
#> 3     C    1    0    1
#> 4     D    0    1    1
#> 5     E    1    1    1
#> 6     F    0    1    1
#> 7     G    1    0    0
#> 8     H    1    1    1
#> 9     I    1    0    1
#> 10    J    1    1    1
#> 11    K    1    1    1
#> 12    L    1    1    0
#> 13    M    0    1    1
#> 14    N    0    1    1
#> 15    O    0    1    1
#> 16    P    1    1    1
#> 17    Q    1    0    1
#> 18    R    1    1    1
#> 19    S    1    1    1
#> 20    T    1    0    1
#> 21    U    0    0    1
#> 22    V    1    1    1
#> 23    W    0    1    1
#> 24    X    0    1    0
#> 25    Y    0    1    1
#> 26    Z    0    1    0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>